# Windows 8 External Hard Drive Enclosure Uselessly Slow

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-8, io

I have just upgraded my operating system to Windows 8, and am trying to use my external hard drive enclosure. However, when I try to use it, it is uselessly slow. Often times Windows explorer will freeze when trying to open up My Computer, and it can take up to a minute just to view the contents of a particular folder, let alone copying files.

This drive worked just fine on Windows 7, so I know the drive is not at fault. It is also in NTFS format. For clarity here is the external hard drive enclosure I am using: http://www.rocketfishproducts.com/products/computer-accessories/RF-AHD35.html

Is there something that can be done about this?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like a drivers issue for the usb controllers, would check the motherboards manufacturer to see if there is a windows 8 driver available. I had one recently that kept blue screening halfway through transfering data. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the upgrade adviser before moving over to windows 8. It is well known that device compatibility is an issue when moving from Windows 7 to windows 8, unfortunately.

Like Spryno said, search for a Windows * driver....or hope that a fix(or driver) will be made available some time soon. I have had my Win8 Pro disc since launch, still haven't installed it and I wont be for some time.

Also, you can try going here: [Microsoft Fix It](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/tips-for-fixing-common-driver-problems)

MS Fix it may find a solution or compatible driver.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue I couldn't figure out - I bought a USB2 PCI card for $10 and let W8 install it's own drivers - USB worked fine. Mine turned out to be the BIOS which needed an update for the USB problem. W8 treated the on board USB as USB1.1 not 2.0

Comment: I'm using a USB 3.0 device... I'll have to check that